# Python-How to save mousellick coordinates in matrix

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

My goal is to record the mouse click coordinates obtained via opencv in a matrix
In this code I try to create a matrix ("list") first. Then I want to append each x,y during each iteration. Error occurs on bolded line and error code basically says the two matrices I try to append are different sizes--but I think they are the same sizes?

Any help appreciated. New to python so might still be stuck on old matlab/c++ ways

```
# importing the module
import cv2
import numpy as np
list = np.array([[1],[1]])

# function to display the coordinates of
# the points clicked on image
def click_event(event,x,y,list,yrow):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        # displaying coordinates on shell
        # print(x,' ',y)
        # storing coordinates as matrix
        coord = np.array([[x],[y]])
        print(coord)
        **matrix = np.hstack((list,coord))**
        print(matrix)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(img,str(x) + ',' + str(y), (x,y), font, 1, (255,0,0),2)
        cv2.imshow('image',img)


# driver fxn
if __name__ == "__main__":
        img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Desktop/image from pin.jpg',1)
        cv2.imshow('image',img)

        cv2.setMouseCallback('image',click_event)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the error is from numpy. you should tag `numpy`. -- pay attention to your variable names. maybe you wanna `print(list)` -- and pay attention to the proper function signature for a mouse callback (consult examples on https://docs.opencv.org if the documentation itself is insufficient) -- you should use plain python lists to *collect* those coordinates. an `append` to a python list is cheaper than a numpy operation because numpy has to allocate a new array every time, but python doesn't have to allocate because it keeps some space beyond what's "in" the list.

Comment: amendment: it's not about the allocations (a tuple costs an allocation too) but about the "growing" numpy array that has to be *copied* every time you need to append something, resulting in O(N^2) effort, while a list can often insert an element at no (allocation/copy) cost, and only sometimes has to be reallocated.

Comment: Just a word of warning, `list` is a keyword in Python, I highly recommend you call it something else e.g. `my_list`